# The request doesn't download the image from url1 but downlaods the image from url2. Both the urls are working

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I have two URLs of images:

[Url 1](https://webtoon-phinf.pstatic.net/20200328_78/1585335418151rxvbz_JPEG/15853354150129524.jpg?type=q90)

[Url 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuyvH.png)

This is my python code

```
img_data = requests.get(url).content 
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as handler: 
     handler.write(img_data)
```

Problem: When I replace url with url1, the image downloaded cannot be opened and has 0kb size, however if I replace url with url2, the image is downloaded with no problems, and I am able to open it.

What is going on? And how can I download the image from url1?

Comment: First link is protected. You will need to add data dictionary to requests.get

Comment: Can you give a code snippet for that?

Comment: I can't access the site. I get  `You don't have permission to access "http://webtoon-phinf.pstatic.net/20200328_78/1585335418151rxvbz_JPEG/15853354150129524.jpg?" on this server.` and no image. I think you are using some private network for that site.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on. Anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: btw is that your own site?

Comment: No, its webtoon comic. Tower of god. here is the link. https://www.webtoons.com/en/ . I was trying to download the comic ep1